# Why do I get StackOverflowEception while recursively filling a LinkedList with random numbers?

Tags: java, list, recursion, linked-list

I need help with the following method:

Our task is to write a recursive method with the head:

```
generateRandoms(int start,int end, int n)
```

The method should generate **n** random numbers between **start** and **end**.

This is what i got:

```
public static List<Integer> generateRandoms(int start,int end, int n) {
    if (n == 0) return null;
    int random = ((int) (Math.random()*((end+1)-start)+start));
    List<Integer> randomList = new LinkedList <Integer>();
    randomList.add(random);
    return randomList.addAll(generateRandoms(start, end, n--));
}
```

The problem is, that this doesnt work, because addAll returns a boolean. I dont have any ideas anymore, can you give me a hint?

Greetings DanielFGA

Comment: This doesnt work. :/Here I get a StackOverflowError Exception.

Comment: If you take a look at the API: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html It is clearly indicated, that the method `addAll()` returns a boolean with true for the list being successful changed or false otherwise. Just put your return statement outside (without the return) and add another line of code after that with: `return randomList;`

Comment: Then I get a StackOverflowError :/

Comment: you can try `Arrays.asList(randomList.addAll(generateRandoms(start, end, n--)));`

Comment: If there is a stackoverflow, then I suppose it won't stop calling your method recursively and therefore overflows the stack. You can try to follow your code path via a debugger and go in step for step

Comment: Do you know what `n--` does? Maybe you should step through the code with a debugger and see what value for `n` you are passing in to the recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three improvements:

1. **DO NOT RETURN `NULL`**. It's to prevent getting a `NullPointerException`. Instead,

   ```
   if(n == 0)
   return new LinkedList<Integer>();
   ```

---

2. Change the statement

   ```
   return randomList.addAll(generateRandoms(start, end, n--));
   ```

   with these two statements:

   ```
   randomList.addAll( generateRandoms(start, end, n-1) );
   return randomList;
   ```

   This is because, as you said, *`addAll()` returns `boolean`*.

   Also, for the `StackOverflowException`:The SOE is thrown because, as [@bradimus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5884788/bradimus) said, you make the recursion call before changing the value of `n`.

   *(The postfix decrement operator changes the value of the variable after the present value is used)*.

   As a result, n's value never reaches 0 and the it leads to infinite recursion. So, the program runs out of memory. Change `n--` with `--n` or `n-1`.

Answer (score 0):

`n--` is your problem. You are making the recursive call before you decrement `n`.

Try

```
return randomList.addAll(generateRandoms(start, end, --n));
```

That should fix your stack overflow. I haven't run your code, but I think you should use

```
if (n == 0) return new LinkedList<>();
```

as well.

Comment: Thank you. The method doesnt run, but the Exception is smaller. :D

Comment: @DanielFGA You're getting a `NullPointerException`. That's why the method does not run.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple Problems:

1. Instead of directly returning the returned value from your addAll call, you have to split it into two operations. First addAll to the randomList and the return that randomList
2. As others have already pointed out you cannot use n--, because that will first pass n and then decrement it after passing it. use --n or n-1 instead
3. You cannot have your method return null, as the method addAll will throw a NullPointerException if you pass null into it. Return an empty List instead.

   ```
   public static List<Integer> generateRandoms(int start,int end, int n) {
       if (n == 0) return Collections.emptyList();
       int random = ((int) (Math.random()*((end+1)-start)+start));
       List<Integer> randomList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
       randomList.add(random);
       randomList.addAll(generateRandoms(start, end, --n));
       return randomList;
   }
   ```